# Can SSL and a key code alone be enough to keep a Web API secure?

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Web API (v2) that will require SSL for all calls made to it, no exceptions. There is no login for the system, instead I plan on providing a user with a <s>secret key</s> key code that will identify them. All future based requests would include this <s>secret key</s> key code as a way to identify and authenticate who that user is.

My question is whether SSL is sufficient enough to keep this secure? Assuming that there is never an insecure connection that contains the secret key do I need to go through other lengths to encrypt or protect it? I've read up on symmetric, asymetric, and hashing methods, but it seems like this may only be redundant if SSL is in place throughout.

This seems too simple, what am I missing?

Some other notes, the <s>secret key</s> key code is not hand entered by the user. It is either stored in a system application (encrypted) or used by another company's API contacting ours.

Comment: It's not a secret if you provide it. It's only a secret if *they* provide it. It sounds like you should be using SSL with mutual authentication.

Comment: Good point, I see my terminology is off there. It would be more of a keycode.

Comment: Since the system application has the potential to have a lot of installations to various end users I don't think mutual SSL would be viable would it? Since it requires a certificate on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that depends on what you mean by "secure" - secure transport? With SSL all you get is secure channel from the app to the server, and identity verification for the server. If you're already using SSL everywhere, the only additional protection I'd recommend is certificate pinning, which protects against rogue CAs (more info and code examples here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). Additionally, make sure your SSL stack on the server is up to spec and disable weak/vulnerable ciphers. I don't think doing additional things to the keycode (encryption, signing) would get you much, if the user doesn't enter anything to authenticate.

I would be more concerned about where you're storing the keycode in the app, and how users are provisioned with it.